# Unable to create a new directory in a mounted path on GCP VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, google-cloud

I have a GCP VM instance. A GCP storage has been mounted in that instance.
I am unable to create a new directory in that mounted directory.

I created the directory using:

```
 mkdir gcs
```

I then mounted the storage using

```
gcsfuse storage_gcp ./gcs
```

When in the GCS directory, i run

```
mkdir new_folder
```

It gives this error
[image]
The system is running Ubuntu 16.

I have tried setting permissions using the following commands, but still permission denied error, when creating new directory.

```
chmod -R 777 ./
chown -R $USER:$USER ./gcs
```

The output for ls -ld gcs

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 29 11:17 gcs
```

How can i create a directory in the mounted path?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the command you are using to create the directory, aswell as any error messages.

Comment: @Panki, updated. Please check now

Comment: Can you show the permissions of the `gcs` folder? The output of `ls -ld gcs` should do the trick. By the way, try replacing pictures of text with text; much easier to read, copy, search etc.

Comment: @berndbausch, this is the output:

`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 29 11:17 gcs`

I have also updated the post with the response of this command

Comment: What user are you logged in as? Provide the output of the command 'id'

Comment: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`. This is the ouput of `id`